# Shopware 6 custom element type image not showing any data on storefront

Tags: shopware6

I have created my component to add some desired config fields in Shopware 6. Everything is working fine but one problem that is image is looking as it is being saved in the administration but is not showing any src or else in dump.

[image: admin image filed Sopware 6]

And here is my dump preiew having `#data` null.

[image: dump image object]

can anyone tell what should I do else here?
I will be very thankful.

Comment: How did you create your custom component? Is it extending an existing class? If I look at the standard image element, there should be an ImageStruct in data. This is created by `\Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Cms\ImageCmsElementResolver` which does not seem to be the case with your custom element.

Comment: yes may be I ignored this. Thank you so much I will have a look upon it this came up with an idea to me.

Comment: Please post the solution when possible

Comment: Hi @Alex thanx for your attention upon this post.
I did not find the solution yet though I am not working on it right now.

Comment: Okay, good luck. Feel free to update the post if you need more help, or post the answer, once you are successfull.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [guide in the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-data-to-cms-elements#overview) that explains exactly what your case is.

You can likely extend the `\Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Cms\ImageCmsElementResolver` and override the `getType` function:

```php
public function getType(): string
{
    return 'my-component-name';
}
```

The important part of the default `ImageCmsElementResolver` is the loading the media information. For that you also need in your CMS element resolver. I explain some parts of the existing ImageCmsElementResolver so you can see which steps you need:

```php
public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
{
    // read the configuration, that is defined in the Admin JS. Likely also media for you
    $mediaConfig = $slot->getFieldConfig()->get('media');

    // if this config is NOT containing useful info
    if (
        $mediaConfig === null
        || $mediaConfig->isMapped()
        || $mediaConfig->isDefault()
        || $mediaConfig->getValue() === null
    ) {
        // return nothing
        return null;
    }

    // otherwise use the configured value as mediaId to load the media entry from the database
    $criteria = new Criteria([$mediaConfig->getStringValue()]);

    $criteriaCollection = new CriteriaCollection();
    $criteriaCollection->add('media_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier(), MediaDefinition::class, $criteria);

    // return the criterias to execute later, when all needed entities for the CMS page are fetched
    return $criteriaCollection;
}
```

Now the data is fetched and as next step you need to put it into a variable accessible from the Twig template. For this you write into the same CMS element resolver this:

```php
public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
{
    $config = $slot->getFieldConfig();
    $image = new ImageStruct();
    // this is important for accessing data in Twig
    $slot->setData($image);

    // read the config again
    $mediaConfig = $config->get('media');
    // if the configuration looks promising
    if ($mediaConfig && $config->isStatic() && $mediaConfig->getValue()) {
        $image->setMediaId($config->getStringValue());

        // look up the media from the entity loading step
        $searchResult = $result->get('media_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier());

        if (!$searchResult) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var MediaEntity|null $media */
        $media = $searchResult->get($config->getValue());

        // if we do not have a media, then skip it
        if (!$media) {
            return;
        }
        // set the media entity to the slot data we just assigned to the slot
        $image->setMedia($media);
    }
}
```

After that you should have more info in the slot variable in Twig to embed a media.